# 3rd display not showing ubuntu 22.04

Tags: nvidia, usb, 22.04, display

I have a Lenovo Ideapad Slim 7 with a display connected into the HDMI port that work well.
I have a second display connected to a Dock via the USB-C.

In display setting, I can see that I have 3 display (Main, 2nd and 3rd)

For some reason, the 3rd display is black with a "No HDMI signal"

On Windows and Mint the 3rd Display was working well, but for some reason since I switch to Ubuntu 22.04 it's not working anymore.

Here is the output of the lshw command:

```
[sudo] password for bougadabougada: 
H/W path               Device           Class          Description
==================================================================
                                        system         82AE (LENOVO_MT_82AE_BU_idea_FM_IdeaPad Slim 7 15IMH05)
/0                                      bus            LNVNB161216
/0/0                                    memory         128KiB BIOS
/0/4                                    processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
/0/4/5                                  memory         384KiB L1 cache
/0/4/6                                  memory         1536KiB L2 cache
/0/4/7                                  memory         12MiB L3 cache
/0/24                                   memory         16GiB System Memory
/0/24/0                                 memory         8GiB Row of chips DDR4 Synchronous 3200 MHz (0.3 ns)
/0/24/1                                 memory         8GiB Row of chips DDR4 Synchronous 3200 MHz (0.3 ns)
/0/100                                  bridge         10th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
/0/100/1                                bridge         6th-10th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16)
/0/100/1/0             /dev/fb0         display        TU117M
/0/100/1/0.1           card0            multimedia     NVIDIA Corporation
/0/100/1/0.1/0         input22          input          HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3
/0/100/1/0.1/1         input23          input          HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7
/0/100/1/0.1/2         input24          input          HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8
/0/100/1/0.1/3         input25          input          HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9
/0/100/2               /dev/fb0         display        CometLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics]
/0/100/4                                generic        Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem
/0/100/12                               generic        Comet Lake PCH Thermal Controller
/0/100/13                               communication  Intel Corporation
/0/100/14                               bus            Comet Lake USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0            usb1             bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/2                           bus            USB2.0 Hub
/0/100/14/0/2/3                         bus            USB2.0 Hub
/0/100/14/0/2/3/3                       bus            USB2.0 Hub
/0/100/14/0/2/3/3/1                     generic        USB-I2C Bridge
/0/100/14/0/2/3/3/2    card1            multimedia     ThinkPad USB-C Dock Gen2 USB Audio
/0/100/14/0/4                           generic        Goodix FingerPrint Device
/0/100/14/0/5                           input          USB Receiver
/0/100/14/0/5/0        input19          input          Logitech M705
/0/100/14/0/6          input26          multimedia     Integrated Camera: Integrated I
/0/100/14/0/e                           communication  AX201 Bluetooth
/0/100/14/1            usb2             bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14.2                             memory         RAM memory
/0/100/14.3            wlp0s20f3        network        Comet Lake PCH CNVi WiFi
/0/100/15                               bus            Comet Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0
/0/100/15.1                             bus            Comet Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1
/0/100/16                               communication  Comet Lake HECI Controller
/0/100/1b                               bridge         Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #17
/0/100/1b/0                             bridge         JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018]
/0/100/1b/0/0                           bridge         JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018]
/0/100/1b/0/0/0                         generic        JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI [Titan Ridge 2C 2018]
/0/100/1b/0/1                           bridge         JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018]
/0/100/1b/0/2                           bridge         JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018]
/0/100/1b/0/2/0                         bus            JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller [Titan Ridge 2C 2018]
/0/100/1b/0/2/0/0      usb3             bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1b/0/2/0/1      usb4             bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1b/0/2/0/1/1                     bus            USB3.1 Hub
/0/100/1b/0/2/0/1/1/1                   generic        USB-C Dock Ethernet
/0/100/1b/0/2/0/1/1/3                   bus            USB3.1 Hub
/0/100/1d                               bridge         Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #9
/0/100/1d/0            /dev/nvme0       storage        SKHynix_HFS512GD9TNG-L3A0B
/0/100/1d/0/0          hwmon3           disk           NVMe disk
/0/100/1d/0/2          /dev/ng0n1       disk           NVMe disk
/0/100/1d/0/1          /dev/nvme0n1     disk           512GB NVMe disk
/0/100/1d/0/1/1        /dev/nvme0n1p1   volume         511MiB Windows FAT volume
/0/100/1d/0/1/2        /dev/nvme0n1p2   volume         1709MiB EXT4 volume
/0/100/1d/0/1/3        /dev/nvme0n1p3   volume         474GiB EFI partition
/0/100/1f                               bridge         Comet Lake LPC Controller
/0/100/1f/0                             system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/1                             system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/2                             system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/3                             system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/4                             generic        PnP device INT3f0d
/0/100/1f/5                             input          PnP device PNP0303
/0/100/1f/6                             system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/7                             system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/8            input21          input          Ideapad extra buttons
/0/100/1f.3            card2            multimedia     Comet Lake PCH cAVS
/0/100/1f.4                             bus            Comet Lake PCH SMBus Controller
/0/100/1f.5                             bus            Comet Lake PCH SPI Controller
/1                                      power          CRB Battery 0
/2                                      power          OEM Define 5
/3                     input0           input          Lid Switch
/4                     input1           input          Power Button
/5                     input2           input          Sleep Button
/6                     input20          input          Intel HID events
/7                     input28          input          SYNA2B5A:00 06CB:CD3E Mouse
/8                     input29          input          SYNA2B5A:00 06CB:CD3E Touchpad
/9                     input3           input          Power Button
/a                     input31          input          sof-hda-dsp Mic
/b                     input32          input          sof-hda-dsp Headphone
/c                     input33          input          sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=3
/d                     input34          input          sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=4
/e                     input35          input          sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=5
/f                     input4           input          AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
/10                    input8           input          Video Bus
/11                    input9           input          Video Bus
/12                    enxf8ce7200400d  network        Ethernet interface
```

Thanks for your help